# putting linq to objects query result into a typed dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

Still kinda new to LINQ.  Seems like there should be a more elegant way to do this using ToDictionary, but can't figure it out.  Here's my code I want to clean up:

```
 var EventOccurrencesMappedToPatientMeds = from pm in allPtMeds
      from e in thisUsersEventOccurrencesPlusEventData
      where e.EventContainer.Event.PatientMedId == pm.MedicationId
      select new ScheduleEventOccurrenceMedPair{ 
           PatientMedication = pm, 
           ScheduledEventOccurrence = e.EventOccurrence 
      };

 int evtOccCount = 1;
 foreach (var evtOcc in EventOccurrencesMappedToPatientMeds)
 {
      // EventOccurrenceChoices is a Dictionary of type <int, IScheduledEventOccurrenceMedPair>
      message.EventOccurrenceChoices.Add(evtOccCount,(ScheduleEventOccurrenceMedPair)evtOcc);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overloaded [Enumerable.Select method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) to include the index, then use `ToDictionary`:

```
var dict = EventOccurrencesMappedToPatientMeds
               .Select((e, i) => new { Event = e, Index = i + 1 })
               .ToDictionary(o => o.Index,
                             o => (ScheduleEventOccurrenceMedPair)o.Event);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToDictionary` extension method.

Something like this:

```
var i = 1;
var resultDictionary = (
    from pm in allPtMeds
    from e in thisUsersEventOccurrencesPlusEventData
    where e.EventContainer.Event.PatientMedId == pm.MedicationId
    select new ScheduleEventOccurrenceMedPair
    {
        PatientMedication = pm,
        ScheduledEventOccurrence = e.EventOccurrence
    })
    .ToDictionary(arg => i++, arg => arg);
```